# How do I request a package to be added to one of the main Conda channels?

Tags: python, conda

I would like to see [parquet-python](https://pypi.org/project/parquet/) in one of the main Conda channels.

Right now it's only in a [small channel and not for Windows](https://anaconda.org/pdrops/parquet-python), so I have to pull it from PIP.

Can anyone give me a hint on what must happen for a package to appear in one of the main Conda channels? Where do I begin to ask?

Comment: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html

Comment: As an FYI both pyarrow and fastparquet are the typical packages for working with parquet files.

Comment: For some reason Fastparquet fails in reading/decoding my parquet files, parquet-python reads them just fine.